# working with JTATransactionManager for transactions?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jta

I am using spring3 and Hibernate4 with Tomcat7.

I have to use JTATransactionManager and i have below configuration.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"  
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">  
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"></property>  
</bean>
```

In above configuration where is `java:comp/UserTransaction` defined?

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify what you want a bit? Do you want an EJB spec, or is the answer `in the JNDI`, or something else?

Comment: i want to know what is java:comp/UserTransaction and where is it configured. Thanks!

Comment: Tomcat doesn't have a JTA transaction manager. You'll need a more complex Java EE container like JBoss, Glassfish, etc. if you want JTA support. Or you'll have to integrate a JTA transaction manager by yourself like Bitronix.

Comment: Nizet, thanks for your reply. I have two applications. App1 is deployed in tomcat and App2 is deployed in JBoss. From App1 am connecting to App2 and doing some database operations. App1 also does some db operations on different database without App2. Sometimes within a single method in App1, i need to call both App2 and App1 own db operations in a single tx. Now how can i use JTATransactionManager here?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Even with two JBoss instances, it would not be a trivial task and you would need to make sure both JBoss instances share the same distributed transaction manager. I wouldn't even try doing that with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It is a JNDI reference to container-supplied user transaction object.

It is not user configurable as such (as in you cannot change the value yourself). The value depends on the EE container you use.

As to what user transaction object really is, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API#UserTransaction_interface):

> UserTransaction interface
>
> The javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface provides the
>   application the ability to control transaction boundaries
>   programmatically. This interface may be used by Java client programs
>   or EJB beans.
>
> The UserTransaction.begin() method starts a global transaction and
>   associates the transaction with the calling thread. The
>   transaction-to-thread association is managed transparently by the
>   Transaction Manager.
>
> Support for nested transactions is not required. The
>   UserTransaction.begin method throws the NotSupportedException when the
>   calling thread is already associated with a transaction and the
>   transaction manager implementation does not support nested
>   transactions.
>
> Transaction context propagation between application programs is
>   provided by the underlying transaction manager implementations on the
>   client and server machines. The transaction context format used for
>   propagation is protocol dependent and must be negotiated between the
>   client and server hosts. For example, if the transaction manager is an
>   implementation of the JTS specification, it will use the transaction
>   context propagation format as specified in the CORBA OTS 1.1
>   specification. Transaction propagation is transparent to application
>   programs..

Answer (score 0):

JTA and associated with it XA transactions are tricky things to implement and support. As @js-nizet said only JEE Application servers have their own transaction managers implementation working out of the box. For lightweight web server like Tomcat or Jetty you have to provide an external implementation and to configure the Spring to work with it. There are a lot of choices so it is up to you. I can recommend you [Jboss' Narayana](http://www.jboss.org/narayana), but it is really up to you. Since it is not so straight-forward to have this running I would recommend you the following blog post which describes everything in a great detail  - [Configuring Spring and JTA without full Java EE](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/).

Here's [another post](http://bgshinhung.blogspot.com/2012/10/integrating-spring-framework-jetty-and.html) on how to configure Narayan with Spring and Jetty.